# Walkthrough the spring source code

Tags: eclipse, spring

I wanted to walkthrough the spring code. For that I cloned the code and built it using `./import-into-eclipse.sh` command. There are some instructions given in README.md file for checking out source in eclipse.

After following above instructions I was able to see the spring code in my eclipse workspace. To refer the spring source from my project I added all of spring projects (like `spring-beans`, `spring-aop` etc) in my project's `Java build path`. I was able to use spring code in my project.

Now the issue is that whenever I run the test cases in my project, I get `initialization error`. I removed spring projects from my java build path and `junit` test started working.

I tried to dig into the issue. For that I tried to run some of the test cases of spring projects itself like `BeanUtilsTests`.

[image]

but I got:

```
    Class not found org.springframework.beans.BeanUtilsTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtilsTests
```

I verified that `classpath` is set:

[image]

Don't know what is the issue. Can someone please tell me that what I did wrong. 
Is there any better way to view/edit spring code?

Comment: A better way to view the source is to just use maven(It will download the source, when you enter in any class(F3 in Eclipse)). This will resovle your problem with the dependencies. To edit the code you're on the right track, but you have to check the license if you're allowed to do that.

Comment: For editing the issue is that I am unable to run test cases in my project. Also spring projects test cases fail with 'initialization error'

Answer (score 1):

Usually the below error,

```
Class not found org.springframework.beans.BeanUtilsTests
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtilsTests
```

occurs when the corresponding jar is missing in the classpath. Since you have already added the `spring-beans` jar manually, I suspect you are using an incompatible version of the `spring-beans` jar with your spring-boot.

You can check the [Maven repo Spring Beans](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-bean) to check the compatible version. But I would suggest using a dependency management tool like Gradle or Maven to include the required dependency jars. [Spring-Boot Gradle file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/settings.gradle)